# How to postback to a different form using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a form with a textbox in it, I want to submit the value of the textbox to another page after an ajax call is successfully made, how can I achieve this?

This is my ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://test.net/getData",
    data: "{some:data}",
    success: function (response) {
            document.forms.form1.txtData.value = "value1";
            document.forms.form1.submit();
    },
    error: function (response) {
            alert("error");
    }
});
```

and then I have my form in page Page1 as:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="hidden" id="txtData" value="" runat="server" />
 </form>
```

But this will send my data back to the original page (Page1) not to Page2 form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify action url in `action` attribute of form.

Take look on [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="Page2.aspx">
    <input type="hidden" id="txtData" value="" runat="server" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use query string, this will redirect to another page with your textvalue

```
success: function (response) {
          var value=response.d   
          //  document.forms.form1.txtData.value = "value1";
          //  document.forms.form1.submit();
            window.location = "http://YourPageName.aspx?id="+value;
    }
```

---

**Code Behind:**
On page load you can retrieve the value by using `Request.QueryString`

```
 if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
   {
          string getTxtValue = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you this works, but since I'm asking for CC info, I prefer not to show it on the url.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the 'action' attribute of the form to action name you need and then submit the form, e.g. like this.

```
success: function (response) {
        var $form = $("#form1");
        $form.attr("action", "your-action-name");
        $form.submit();
},
```

[About HTML  action Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp)

Comment: Thank you this is a great approach however I go with the other one since I already know the url to post and it's easier to just put it in the tag.